# Disable <Marker /> touch events and interactions react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Is there any cross platform solution to either disabling all touch events for a marker in react-native-maps, or for adding custom views to the map in some other way such that they don't have any touch interactions?

I'm needing to add icons to my map alongside typical pressable markers, and placing those markers on the map via the `Marker` component causes them to receive touch events which can cause issues. Disabling interactions or some sort of nontouchable component would be awesome.

Comment: Can you try `pointerEvents="none"` prop?

Comment: @UğurEren I have tried that it does not work. Doesn't seem like it does anything at all on a marker.